# php query is called before form and submit button

Tags: php

Trying to update database row field once `Submit` is pressed. there are 3 different files which are responsible for this :

**inc.deal-list.php**

```
echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="disapproveDeal(' . $row[$primaryKey] . ')" title="' . t_lang('M_TXT_MARK_REJECTED') . '">' . t_lang('M_TXT_MARK_REJECTED') . '</a></li>';`
```

**deals.js**

```
function disapproveDeal(id){
    jQuery.facebox(function() {
        callAjax('deals-ajax.php', 'mode=disapproveDeal&id='+id, function(t){
            var ans=parseJsonData(t);
            if(ans===false){
                $.facebox(txtoops + t);
                return;
            }
            $.facebox(ans.msg);
            if(ans.status==0) return;
            location.reload();
        });
    });
}
```

**deals-ajax.php**

```
$x=$db->query("SELECT reject_reason FROM tbl_deals WHERE deal_id=" . $post['id']);
$y=$db->fetch($x);

?>
<div class="box"><div class="title"><?php echo t_lang('M_TXT_PUT_NOTES'); ?></div><div class="content"> 
<form method="post" id="" >
    <table class="tbl_form"> 
        <tr>
            <td> 
                <b><?php  echo t_lang('M_TXT_REASON');?></b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name_reject_reason" id="" value="<?php echo $y['reject_reason']?>" required/></td>
        </tr><br>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
      
if(!empty($_POST['name_reject_reason'])) {
    if (!$db->update_from_array('tbl_deals', array('deal_status' => 5, 'reject_reason' => $_POST['submit']), 'deal_id=' . $post['id'])){
        dieJsonError($db->getError());
    } else {
    dieJsonSuccess(t_lang('M_TXT_DEAL') . ' ' . t_lang('M_TXT_DISAPPROVED'));
   }
}
   
break;
```

The problem is : when Reject Deal button is pressed it pops up the form. But it doesn't send the data in the field of `$_POST['name_reject_reason']`  .

DB query is done before pressing `Submit` button of the form, however , it should wait for form and take the data from the text input (name_reject_reason) and send it to db. Tried almost everything but no success. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with bound parameters instead of injection user data directly into the queries like that! It's not only about security, but if any of the posted values contains certain characters (like a a single `'`), your queries will break

Comment: Also, what's the relationship between the javascript code and the form? It's _very_ unclear at the moment.. Please edit your question and include a proper explanation and a step by step what you're doing and what happens/should happen on each step and make sure you have posted _all_ relevant code (and have removed anything not relevant). Also, JS is calling `deals-ajax.php` while it says `deal-ajax.php` over the PHP code. Is it the same file with a typo in one of the places, or are they two different files?

Comment: I have edited my first post. The file name was a typo mistake , it should be deals-ajax.php. additionally I have edited my db query and now it is not open for sql injection. what I need is when I press the button pop up window comes. and in that form there is a text place where we put the text there. once we press Submit  button of that form it should send the data  to database as it is mentioned. But it always send empty data.